# Automatically fiting experimental data using NonLinearModelFit

Tags: fitting

Please, I have been working for some time to perform an automatic fit of my experimental data using an analytical function developed from a model based on the theory of kinematical diffraction.

The idea is to find the  parameters (`b, t, m, L`) corresponding to the best fit. So far, I have only been able to perform a manual fit. But when I try to do an automatic fit using the function 'FindFit' or 'NonlinearModelFit', neither of the two provide me with a solution. After having a look on some couple of solutions proposed in the forum, I conclude that the analytical function used to fit the data might be the problem.

I am a new Mathematica user, not a professional programmer, but I am willing to learn. Please, any solution helping me to fit my data would be very welcome. The code is below.

I do not know how to upload the expe. data file, therefore I copied and paste it.

```
(******* Experimental Data *******)

data = {{-0.0240482,-1.81326},{-0.0239912,-1.73542},{-0.0239342,-1.45053},{-0.0238772,-1.22645},{-0.0238202,-1.0405},{-0.0237632,-0.77869},{-0.0237063,-0.497861},{-0.0236493,-0.259655},{-0.0235923,-0.0823257},{-0.0235353,-0.0318},{-0.0234783,0.0531861},{-0.0234213,0.0445949},{-0.0233643,-0.30208},{-0.0233074,-1.26823},{-0.0232504,-1.52536},{-0.0231934,-1.68997},{-0.0231364,-1.74257},{-0.0230794,-1.83779},{-0.0230224,-1.95102},{-0.0229654,-2.0238},{-0.0229085,-2.0797},{-0.0228515,-2.12749},{-0.0227945,-2.13166},{-0.0227375,-2.17023},{-0.0226805,-2.16627},{-0.0226235,-2.16424},{-0.0225665,-2.16236},{-0.0225096,-2.1559},{-0.0224526,-2.15125},{-0.0223956,-2.22758},{-0.0223386,-2.39086},{-0.0222816,-2.41948},{-0.0222246,-2.46173},{-0.0221676,-2.45458},{-0.0221106,-2.50036},{-0.0220537,-2.47597},{-0.0219967,-2.45513},{-0.0219397,-2.51579},{-0.0218827,-2.47304},{-0.0218257,-2.48605},{-0.0217687,-2.45129},{-0.0217117,-2.3948},{-0.0216548,-2.29378},{-0.0215978,-2.2838},{-0.0215408,-2.25057},{-0.0214838,-2.20268},{-0.0214268,-2.26881},{-0.0213698,-2.36599},{-0.0213128,-2.40492},{-0.0212559,-2.40551},{-0.0211989,-2.38133},{-0.0211419,-2.37128},{-0.0210849,-2.36717},{-0.0210279,-2.37263},{-0.0209709,-2.35605},{-0.0209139,-2.3188},{-0.020857,-2.27561},{-0.0208,-2.22494},{-0.020743,-2.15167},{-0.020686,-2.03491},{-0.020629,-1.99562},{-0.020572,-1.93279},{-0.020515,-1.9041},{-0.020458,-1.92548},{-0.0204011,-2.03569},{-0.0203441,-2.05815},{-0.0202871,-1.99919},{-0.0202301,-1.96485},{-0.0201731,-1.90343},{-0.0201161,-1.83458},{-0.0200591,-1.71522},{-0.0200022,-1.34334},{-0.0199452,-1.00972},{-0.0198882,-0.759807},{-0.0198312,-0.531968},{-0.0197742,-0.276069},{-0.0197172,-0.0262041},{-0.0196602,0.19532},{-0.0196033,0.23909},{-0.0195463,0.320668},{-0.0194893,0.340291},{-0.0194323,0.06475},{-0.0193753,-1.01243},{-0.0193183,-1.31493},{-0.0192613,-1.45398},{-0.0192044,-1.52927},{-0.0191474,-1.61448},{-0.0190904,-1.72186},{-0.0190334,-1.7674},{-0.0189764,-1.78645},{-0.0189194,-1.81483},{-0.0188624,-1.8122},{-0.0188054,-1.83276},{-0.0187485,-1.77184},{-0.0186915,-1.70848},{-0.0186345,-1.69685},{-0.0185775,-1.66327},{-0.0185205,-1.63792},{-0.0184635,-1.75626},{-0.0184065,-1.92733},{-0.0183496,-1.95626},{-0.0182926,-1.95523},{-0.0182356,-1.99048},{-0.0181786,-2.00506},{-0.0181216,-1.97263},{-0.0180646,-2.00856},{-0.0180076,-1.98286},{-0.0179507,-1.99435},{-0.0178937,-1.96325},{-0.0178367,-1.88783},{-0.0177797,-1.78381},{-0.0177227,-1.68787},{-0.0176657,-1.63688},{-0.0176087,-1.62247},{-0.0175518,-1.62042},{-0.0174948,-1.76724},{-0.0174378,-2.02084},{-0.0173808,-2.15678},{-0.0173238,-2.19226},{-0.0172668,-2.25504},{-0.0172098,-2.31423},{-0.0171528,-2.36157},{-0.0170959,-2.34712},{-0.0170389,-2.34767},{-0.0169819,-2.38444},{-0.0169249,-2.3965},{-0.0168679,-2.41865},{-0.0168109,-2.42785},{-0.0167539,-2.42284},{-0.016697,-2.43986},{-0.01664,-2.41052},{-0.016583,-2.43452},{-0.016526,-2.46266},{-0.016469,-2.48967},{-0.016412,-2.50556},{-0.016355,-2.48099},{-0.0162981,-2.44751},{-0.0162411,-2.41455},{-0.0161841,-2.31878},{-0.0161271,-2.26112},{-0.0160701,-1.78756},{-0.0160131,-1.41864},{-0.0159561,-1.21275},{-0.0158992,-0.975437},{-0.0158422,-0.688694},{-0.0157852,-0.409156},{-0.0157282,-0.260388},{-0.0156712,-0.220808},{-0.0156142,-0.138843},{-0.0155572,-0.160181},{-0.0155002,-0.584171},{-0.0154433,-1.60568},{-0.0153863,-1.8307},{-0.0153293,-1.92421},{-0.0152723,-1.92228},{-0.0152153,-1.99669},{-0.0151583,-2.04497},{-0.0151013,-2.0652},{-0.0150444,-2.02528},{-0.0149874,-2.05857},{-0.0149304,-2.04167},{-0.0148734,-1.98113},{-0.0148164,-1.91877},{-0.0147594,-1.85719},{-0.0147024,-1.81132},{-0.0146455,-1.75004},{-0.0145885,-1.76104},{-0.0145315,-1.87269},{-0.0144745,-1.97751},{-0.0144175,-1.97303},{-0.0143605,-1.95133},{-0.0143035,-1.93812},{-0.0142466,-1.91414},{-0.0141896,-1.91244},{-0.0141326,-1.8895},{-0.0140756,-1.88},{-0.0140186,-1.7915},{-0.0139616,-1.72628},{-0.0139046,-1.60982},{-0.0138476,-1.50794},{-0.0137907,-1.37058},{-0.0137337,-1.3168},{-0.0136767,-1.28625},{-0.0136197,-1.27518},{-0.0135627,-1.41303},{-0.0135057,-1.69524},{-0.0134487,-1.83509},{-0.0133918,-1.87082},{-0.0133348,-1.88469},{-0.0132778,-1.92229},{-0.0132208,-1.93458},{-0.0131638,-1.92521},{-0.0131068,-1.88975},{-0.0130498,-1.93906},{-0.0129929,-1.92025},{-0.0129359,-1.88657},{-0.0128789,-1.84528},{-0.0128219,-1.78502},{-0.0127649,-1.73014},{-0.0127079,-1.71764},{-0.0126509,-1.67656},{-0.012594,-1.76685},{-0.012537,-1.94884},{-0.01248,-1.9754},{-0.012423,-1.96123},{-0.012366,-1.96204},{-0.012309,-1.93664},{-0.012252,-1.91499},{-0.012195,-1.81067},{-0.0121381,-1.34888},{-0.0120811,-1.05175},{-0.0120241,-0.851894},{-0.0119671,-0.574415},{-0.0119101,-0.267068},{-0.0118531,0.0216929},{-0.0117961,0.133511},{-0.0117392,0.179129},{-0.0116822,0.284151},{-0.0116252,0.162886},{-0.0115682,-0.514862},{-0.0115112,-1.42774},{-0.0114542,-1.73293},{-0.0113972,-1.8503},{-0.0113403,-1.9404},{-0.0112833,-2.06367},{-0.0112263,-2.1096},{-0.0111693,-2.1643},{-0.0111123,-2.16087},{-0.0110553,-2.21029},{-0.0109983,-2.24697},{-0.0109414,-2.24677},{-0.0108844,-2.25423},{-0.0108274,-2.23154},{-0.0107704,-2.23813},{-0.0107134,-2.23926},{-0.0106564,-2.20911},{-0.0105994,-2.26066},{-0.0105424,-2.22659},{-0.0104855,-2.19798},{-0.0104285,-2.20054},{-0.0103715,-2.17932},{-0.0103145,-2.13512},{-0.0102575,-2.13751},{-0.0102005,-2.09929},{-0.0101435,-2.08432},{-0.0100866,-2.03684},{-0.0100296,-1.97185},{-0.00997259,-1.8733},{-0.0099156,-1.78133},{-0.00985861,-1.68903},{-0.00980163,-1.62204},{-0.00974464,-1.59357},{-0.00968765,-1.59105},{-0.00963067,-1.69349},{-0.00957368,-1.83792},{-0.0095167,-1.8851},{-0.00945971,-1.89841},{-0.00940272,-1.86893},{-0.00934574,-1.87453},{-0.00928875,-1.85286},{-0.00923177,-1.83693},{-0.00917478,-1.82872},{-0.00911779,-1.81087},{-0.00906081,-1.7821},{-0.00900382,-1.75166},{-0.00894683,-1.67885},{-0.00888985,-1.60178},{-0.00883286,-1.58332},{-0.00877588,-1.54338},{-0.00871889,-1.53052},{-0.0086619,-1.59064},{-0.00860492,-1.6714},{-0.00854793,-1.66151},{-0.00849094,-1.63692},{-0.00843396,-1.60028},{-0.00837697,-1.5458},{-0.00831999,-1.45734},{-0.008263,-1.18708},{-0.00820601,-0.503602},{-0.00814903,-0.215419},{-0.00809204,-0.00639811},{-0.00803505,0.297702},{-0.00797807,0.570587},{-0.00792108,0.841306},{-0.0078641,0.972445},{-0.00780711,1.0079},{-0.00775012,1.10936},{-0.00769314,1.00056},{-0.00763615,0.292107},{-0.00757917,-0.752531},{-0.00752218,-1.04105},{-0.00746519,-1.19685},{-0.00740821,-1.3118},{-0.00735122,-1.40973},{-0.00729423,-1.50052},{-0.00723725,-1.54108},{-0.00718026,-1.58967},{-0.00712328,-1.61237},{-0.00706629,-1.6306},{-0.0070093,-1.62929},{-0.00695232,-1.6351},{-0.00689533,-1.59759},{-0.00683834,-1.5877},{-0.00678136,-1.58514},{-0.00672437,-1.59424},{-0.00666739,-1.69949},{-0.0066104,-1.76621},{-0.00655341,-1.76053},{-0.00649643,-1.79124},{-0.00643944,-1.77199},{-0.00638245,-1.7897},{-0.00632547,-1.80411},{-0.00626848,-1.8128},{-0.0062115,-1.80599},{-0.00615451,-1.81455},{-0.00609752,-1.78912},{-0.00604054,-1.80638},{-0.00598355,-1.77455},{-0.00592657,-1.77492},{-0.00586958,-1.74962},{-0.00581259,-1.75867},{-0.00575561,-1.75639},{-0.00569862,-1.78255},{-0.00564163,-1.80791},{-0.00558465,-1.81798},{-0.00552766,-1.8128},{-0.00547068,-1.82566},{-0.00541369,-1.80622},{-0.0053567,-1.79731},{-0.00529972,-1.79003},{-0.00524273,-1.77817},{-0.00518574,-1.76425},{-0.00512876,-1.76869},{-0.00507177,-1.73787},{-0.00501479,-1.74111},{-0.0049578,-1.70497},{-0.00490081,-1.69925},{-0.00484383,-1.68787},{-0.00478684,-1.6715},{-0.00472985,-1.66732},{-0.00467287,-1.6767},{-0.00461588,-1.64584},{-0.0045589,-1.59636},{-0.00450191,-1.53702},{-0.00444492,-1.47968},{-0.00438794,-1.37911},{-0.00433095,-0.914447},{-0.00427397,-0.224023},{-0.00421698,0.0271532},{-0.00415999,0.271859},{-0.00410301,0.581839},{-0.00404602,0.861706},{-0.00398903,1.14676},{-0.00393205,1.2464},{-0.00387506,1.28071},{-0.00381808,1.35369},{-0.00376109,1.23321},{-0.0037041,0.367003},{-0.00364712,-0.62981},{-0.00359013,-0.925617},{-0.00353314,-1.09072},{-0.00347616,-1.18579},{-0.00341917,-1.29053},{-0.00336219,-1.3478},{-0.0033052,-1.38787},{-0.00324821,-1.40483},{-0.00319123,-1.43341},{-0.00313424,-1.43496},{-0.00307726,-1.41387},{-0.00302027,-1.39441},{-0.00296328,-1.36197},{-0.0029063,-1.35316},{-0.00284931,-1.33591},{-0.00279232,-1.36956},{-0.00273534,-1.46653},{-0.00267835,-1.48467},{-0.00262137,-1.49918},{-0.00256438,-1.50051},{-0.00250739,-1.49217},{-0.00245041,-1.49307},{-0.00239342,-1.49867},{-0.00233643,-1.47606},{-0.00227945,-1.46736},{-0.00222246,-1.46003},{-0.00216548,-1.42948},{-0.00210849,-1.35499},{-0.0020515,-1.27771},{-0.00199452,-1.21692},{-0.00193753,-1.19714},{-0.00188054,-1.17166},{-0.00182356,-1.22041},{-0.00176657,-1.36436},{-0.00170959,-1.47371},{-0.0016526,-1.50218},{-0.00159561,-1.52746},{-0.00153863,-1.5334},{-0.00148164,-1.54329},{-0.00142466,-1.54814},{-0.00136767,-1.54341},{-0.00131068,-1.55056},{-0.0012537,-1.54236},{-0.00119671,-1.55812},{-0.00113972,-1.55891},{-0.00108274,-1.53027},{-0.00102575,-1.53054},{-0.000968765,-1.51149},{-0.000911779,-1.49807},{-0.000854793,-1.51134},{-0.000797807,-1.51897},{-0.000740821,-1.52806},{-0.000683834,-1.5155},{-0.000626848,-1.47407},{-0.000569862,-1.46806},{-0.000512876,-1.40529},{-0.00045589,-1.26877},{-0.000398903,-0.542312},{-0.000341917,-0.0312396},{-0.000284931,0.247409},{-0.000227945,0.472969},{-0.000170959,0.741842},{-0.000113972,1.03872},{-0.0000569862,1.26407},{0.,1.29548},{0.0000569862,1.36335},{0.000113972,1.4046},{0.000170959,1.04329},{0.000227945,-0.269656},{0.000284931,-0.807027},{0.000341917,-1.00622},{0.000398903,-1.11193},{0.00045589,-1.06733},{0.000512876,-0.943579},{0.000569862,-0.765724},{0.000626848,-0.727541},{0.000683834,-0.683965},{0.000740821,-0.641479},{0.000797807,-0.809977},{0.000854793,-1.41627},{0.000911779,-1.4921},{0.000968765,-1.49609},{0.00102575,-1.49211},{0.00108274,-1.49222},{0.00113972,-1.52292},{0.00119671,-1.54531},{0.0012537,-1.54851},{0.00131068,-1.54517},{0.00136767,-1.53932},{0.00142466,-1.53543},{0.00148164,-1.54694},{0.00153863,-1.53014},{0.00159561,-1.51856},{0.0016526,-1.50454},{0.00170959,-1.46617},{0.00176657,-1.41256},{0.00182356,-1.3221},{0.00188054,-1.25399},{0.00193753,-1.20869},{0.00199452,-1.17907},{0.0020515,-1.18237},{0.00210849,-1.29103},{0.00216548,-1.4211},{0.00222246,1.47526},{0.00227945,-1.48766},{0.00233643,-1.50361},{0.00239342,1.5059},{0.00245041,1.50298},{0.00250739,-1.49684},{0.00256438,1.49744},{0.00262137,1.4862},{0.00267835, o.4681},{0.00273534,-1.47287},{0.00279232,1.43808},{0.00284931,.39778},{0.0029063,1.36972},{0.00296328,1.34384},{0.003020271.33377},{0.00307726,1.39418},{0.00313424,-1.47907},{0.00319123,1.46911},{0.00324821,1.44302},{0.0033052,1.41389},{0.00336219,1.37406},{0.00341917,1.29447},{0.00347616,0.957527},{0.00353314,0.271497},{0.00359013,0.0526861},{0.00364712,0.301951},{0.0037041,0.565042},{0.00376109,0.859746},{0.00381808,1.15511},{0.00387506,1.23606},{0.00393205,1.27066},{0.00398903,1.35967},{0.00404602,1.1791},{0.00410301,0.093776},{0.00415999,0.693469},{0.00421698,0.96206},{0.00427397,1.15351},{0.00433095,1.26862},{0.00438794,1.3858},{0.00444492,1.46648},{0.00450191,1.52352},{0.0045589,1.5539},{0.00461588,1.59517},{0.00467287,1.63476},{0.00472985,1.65089},{0.00478684,1.652},{0.00484383,1.65461},{0.00490081,1.67489},{0.0049578,1.67361},{0.00501479,1.7042},{0.00507177,1.71873},{0.00512876,1.74988},{0.00518574,1.75948},{0.00524273,1.77294},{0.00529972,1.77168},{0.0053567,1.77132},{0.00541369,1.78816},{0.00547068,1.79223},{0.00552766,1.79294},{0.00558465,1.79312},{0.00564163,1.78279},{0.00569862,1.78754},{0.00575561,1.77901},{0.00581259,1.74302},{0.00586958,1.72674},{0.00592657,1.72943},{0.00598355,1.7529},{0.00604054,1.77873},{0.00609752,-1.79916},{0.00615451,1.79409},{0.0062115,-1.7969},{0.00626848,1.79087},{0.00632547,1.78494},{0.00638245,1.78681},{0.00643944,1.78023},{0.00649643,1.7634},{0.00655341,1.74293},{0.0066104,1.74551},{0.00666739,1.70421},{0.00672437,1.67238},{0.00678136,1.63526},{0.00683834,1.60748},{0.00689533,1.56259},{0.00695232,1.57509},{0.0070093,1.6472},{0.00706629,1.66127},{0.00712328,1.63805},{0.00718026,1.59839},{0.00723725,1.53708},{0.00729423,1.48965},{0.00735122,1.37029},{0.00740821,0.730106},{0.00746519,0.328012},{0.00752218,0.112803},{0.00757917,0.145645},{0.00763615,0.468527},{0.00769314,0.763894},{0.00775012,0.954003},{0.00780711,0.98727},{0.0078641,1.06387},{0.00792108,1.08129},{0.00797807,0.685812},{0.00803505,0.533091},{0.00809204,0.957587},{0.00814903,1.16626},{0.00820601,1.26538},{0.008263,1.38621},{0.00831999,1.47834},{0.00837697,1.53234},{0.00843396,1.55936},{0.00849094,1.62185},{0.00854793,1.64683},{0.00860492,1.65727},{0.0086619,1.61644},{0.00871889,1.56785},{0.00877588,1.56561},{0.00883286,1.53008},{0.00888985,1.54001},{0.00894683,1.62197},{0.00900382,1.75213},{0.00906081,1.78792},{0.00911779,1.81026},{0.00917478,1.80385},{0.00923177,1.81934},{0.00928875,1.84728},{0.00934574,-1.83298},{0.00940272,1.8375},{0.00945971,1.84792},{0.0095167,1.83502},{0.00957368,1.78656},{0.00963067,1.74159},{0.00968765,1.66394},{0.00974464,-1.60434},{0.00980163,1.59187},{0.00985861,1.60452},{0.0099156,1.72262},{0.00997259,1.91777},{0.0100296,2.02747},{0.0100866,2.06882},{0.0101435,2.08862},{0.0102005,2.12173},{0.0102575,2.14325},{0.0103145,2.12628},{0.0103715,2.15082},{0.0104285,2.18094},{0.0104855,2.21672},{0.0105424,2.20683},{0.0105994,2.23228},{0.0106564,2.25192},{0.0107134,2.21437},{0.0107704,2.20599},{0.0108274,2.24309},{0.0108844,2.2327},{0.0109414,2.23711},{0.0109983,2.22841},{0.0110553,2.23257},{0.0111123,2.21155},{0.0111693,-2.18494},{0.0112263,2.11458},{0.0112833,1.96815},{0.0113403,1.38442},{0.0113972,1.06612},{0.0114542,0.85312},{0.0115112,0.581212},{0.0115682,0.290072},{0.0116252,0.0106204},{0.0116822,0.13199},{0.0117392,0.173554},{0.0117961,0.276758},{0.0118531,0.157072},{0.0119101,0.546365},{0.0119671,1.42711},{0.0120241,1.65166},{0.0120811,1.75683},{0.0121381,1.79785},{0.012195,1.88014},{0.012252,1.94621},{0.012309,1.92997},{0.012366,1.9322},{0.012423,1.95054},{0.01248,1.9304},{0.012537,1.89325},{0.012594,1.83258},{0.0126509,1.78368},{0.0127079,1.75376},{0.0127649,1.70537},{0.0128219,1.70915},{0.0128789,1.82948},{0.0129359,1.91244},{0.0129929,1.91128},{0.0130498,1.9051},{0.0131068,1.90382},{0.0131638,1.90891},{0.0132208,1.90949},{0.0132778,1.89322},{0.0133348,1.8458},{0.0133918,1.82136},{0.0134487,1.73364},{0.0135057,1.62843},{0.0135627,1.49069},{0.0136197,1.36607},{0.0136767,1.32614},{0.0137337,1.27641},{0.0137907,1.28812},{0.0138476,1.4645},{0.0139046,1.69601},{0.0139616,1.82247},{0.0140186,1.8676},{0.0140756,1.88873},{0.0141326,1.94914},{0.0141896,1.95684},{0.0142466,1.95827},{0.0143035,1.93063},{0.0143605,1.96886},{0.0144175,1.94627},{0.0144745,1.97236},{0.0145315,1.88562},{0.0145885,1.81842},{0.0146455,1.82203},{0.0147024,1.78748},{0.0147594,1.76895},{0.0148164,1.89514},{0.0148734,2.04818},{0.0149304,2.07421},{0.0149874,2.057},{0.0150444,2.03217},{0.0151013,2.02752},{0.0151583,2.02866},{0.0152153,1.83424},{0.0152723,1.48155},{0.0153293,1.24782},{0.0153863,1.03669},{0.0154433,0.789758},{0.0155002,0.506515},{0.0155572,0.293778},{0.0156142,0.23594},{0.0156712,0.165301},{0.0157282,0.128584},{0.0157852,0.395774},{0.0158422,1.47663},{0.0158992,1.85366},{0.0159561,2.05721},{0.0160131,2.1025},{0.0160701,2.24607},{0.0161271,2.29555},{0.0161841,2.33592},{0.0162411,2.42123},{0.0162981,2.41333},{0.016355,2.44918},{0.016412,2.47728},{0.016469,2.41312},{0.016526,2.44813},{0.016583,2.43414},{0.01664,2.41643},{0.016697,2.37344},{0.0167539,2.37924},{0.0168109,2.45329},{0.0168679,2.40993},{0.0169249,2.41854},{0.0169819,2.40577},{0.0170389,2.36486},{0.0170959,2.3313},{0.0171528,2.27569},{0.0172098,2.22744},{0.0172668,2.17128},{0.0173238,2.12084},{0.0173808,1.9782},{0.0174378,1.83023},{0.0174948,1.72598},{0.0175518,1.67164},{0.0176087,1.6138},{0.0176657,1.61663},{0.0177227,1.74782},{0.0177797,1.93176},{0.0178367,1.98672},{0.0178937,2.01964},{0.0179507,2.0326},{0.0180076,2.03999},{0.0180646,2.01198},{0.0181216,1.99902},{0.0181786,1.97795},{0.0182356,1.97682},{0.0182926,1.95968},{0.0183496,1.89954},{0.0184065,1.82794},{0.0184635,1.72735},{0.0185205,1.70089},{0.0185775,1.6493},{0.0186345,1.65082},{0.0186915,1.7734},{0.0187485,1.87505},{0.0188054,1.86174},{0.0188624,1.83644},{0.0189194,1.79757},{0.0189764,1.75606},{0.0190334,1.68375},{0.0190904,1.4319},{0.0191474,1.06028},{0.0192044,0.827},{0.0192613,0.607339},{0.0193183,0.343936},{0.0193753,0.0607711},{0.0194323,0.176928},{0.0194893,0.232459},{0.0195463,0.288945},{0.0196033,0.34296},{0.0196602,0.124294},{0.0197172,0.830944},{0.0197742,1.27586},{0.0198312,1.48256},{0.0198882,1.55914},{0.0199452,1.66246},{0.0200022,1.81027},{0.0200591,1.87068},{0.0201161,1.88659},{0.0201731,1.9636},{0.0202301,2.03057},{0.0202871,2.04145},{0.0203441,2.02777},{0.0204011,1.97417},{0.020458,1.94868},{0.020515,1.95265},{0.020572,1.93248},{0.020629,2.002},{0.020686,2.18558},{0.020743,2.24562},{0.0208,2.24873},{0.020857,2.29548},{0.0209139,2.33814},{0.0209709,2.34582},{0.0210279,2.35011},{0.0210849,2.39165},{0.0211419,2.36313},{0.0211989,2.40821},{0.0212559,2.36345},{0.0213128,2.3467},{0.0213698,2.31578},{0.0214268,2.2478},{0.0214838,2.23875},{0.0215408,2.25149},{0.0215978,2.27208},{0.0216548,2.4043},{0.0217117,2.46251},{0.0217687,2.48954},{0.0218257,2.52055},{0.0218827,2.49878},{0.0219397,2.5097},{0.0219967,2.49202},{0.0220537,2.46584},{0.0221106,2.4496},{0.0221676,2.49369},{0.0222246,2.45245},{0.0222816,2.34247},{0.0223386,2.29435},{0.0223956,2.21183},{0.0224526,2.19697},{0.0225096,2.14364},{0.0225665,2.15235},{0.0226235,2.22693},{0.0226805,2.225},{0.0227375,2.22589},{0.0227945,2.16654},{0.0228515,2.09773},{0.0229085,2.0086},{0.0229654,1.94496},{0.0230224,1.6025},{0.0230794,1.30574},{0.0231364,1.10033},{0.0231934,0.85465},{0.0232504,0.553196},{0.0233074,0.293706},{0.0233643,0.0964459},{0.0234213,0.043839},{0.0234783,0.0356686},{0.0235353,0.0382588},{0.0235923,0.239778},{0.0236493,1.18129},{0.0237063,1.45936},{0.0237632,1.59958},{0.0238202,1.64297},{0.0238772,1.73546},{0.0239342,1.82179},{0.0239912,1.86846},{0.0240482,1.86435},{0.0241052,1.92155},{0.0241622,1.95749},{0.0242191,1.9245},{0.0242761,1.88484},{0.0243331,1.79776},{0.0243901,1.76435},{0.0244471,1.72893},{0.0245041,1.69591},{0.0245611,1.81515},{0.024618,1.9799},{0.024675,2.01189},{0.024732,2.02256},{0.024789,2.02546},{0.024846,2.07948},{0.024903,2.05634},{0.02496,2.04718},{0.0250169,2.03915},{0.0250739,1.9736}}

(***********Analytical model************)


Ica[(θ_)?NumericQ, (ϕ_)?NumericQ, (λ_)?NumericQ, (α_)?NumericQ, (L_)?NumericQ, (b_)?NumericQ, (t_)?NumericQ, 
(m_)?NumericQ, (n_)?NumericQ] := FullSimplify[
-((2*λ^2*(-1 + Cos[L*m*n])*Cos[α]^2*
   (n^2*λ^2*(-2 - Cos[b*n] + Cos[t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ - n*Tan[α])] + 
      Cos[t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ + n*Tan[α])] - Cos[n*(b + 2*t*Tan[α])] + 
      Cos[b*n - t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ - n*Tan[α])] + 
      Cos[b*n + t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ + n*Tan[α])])*Sin[α]^2 + 
    2*n*Pi*λ*(Cos[t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ - n*Tan[α])] - 
      Cos[t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ + n*Tan[α])])*Sin[2*α]*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]) + 
    4*Pi^2*Cos[α]^2*(-2 + Cos[b*n] + Cos[t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ - n*Tan[α])] + 
      Cos[t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ + n*Tan[α])] + Cos[n*(b + 2*t*Tan[α])] - 
      Cos[b*n - t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ - n*Tan[α])] - 
      Cos[b*n + t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ + n*Tan[α])])*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ])^2))/
  (L^2*n^2*(-1 + Cos[L*n])*(n*λ*Sin[α] - 2*Pi*Cos[α]*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))^2*
   (n*λ*Sin[α] + 2*Pi*Cos[α]*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))^2))]; 

rr = Pi/180; 
θ = 0.134;
ϕ = 0.133;
λ = 1.0353234;
α = 0.1;
t = 570 // Rationalize;
b = 434 // Rationalize;
L = 1600 // Rationalize;
m = 41 // Rationalize; 

Ccal0 = Ica[θ*rr, ϕ*rr, λ, α*rr, L, b, t, m, 0.0000364797082]*(Exp[-280*0.0000364797082^2]/850) + (1.1*Random[])/10^3.5; 

Ccal = Ica[θ*rr, ϕ*rr, λ, α*rr, L, b, t, m, n]*(Exp[-280*n^2]/850) + (1.1*Random[])/10^3.5;



fig = Show[{LogPlot[Ccal/Ccal0, {n, -0.11, 0.11}, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> Red]}]


(****** Automatic Fitting *****)

Union[{Head[#], Length[#], And @@ (NumberQ /@ #)} & /@ Qscan220];



    MyAutoFit = NonlinearModelFit[data, Ccal/Ccal0, {b, m, t, L}, n];

Show[{Plot[Ica[θ,ϕ,λ,α,L,b,t,m,n]/.MyAutoFit,{n, -0.11, 0.11},Epilog->{Red,AbsolutePointSize[3],Point[data,{i,1,ll}]]},PlotRange->All,PlotTheme->"Scientific",PlotStyle->{Blue, Thick}]}, {ListLinePlot[Qscan220-Table[{0,1.4},{i,1,ll}], PlotTheme->"Scientific",PlotStyle->{Darker[Gray],Dashed, Thick}]}, Joined->{False, True}, LabelStyle->{25,GrayLevel[-5]},FrameLabel->{{HoldForm["Log Intensity (a. u.)"], None},{RawBoxes["Qx (1/Angst.)"],None}}]
```

The values of b, m, t, L that are provided are the initial values. The error meassages:

```
NonlinearModelFit::eqineq: Constraints in {Log[0.000128665 +1/850 E^(-280 n^2) Ica[(67 \[Pi])/90000,(133 \[Pi])/180000,1.03532,\[Pi]/1800,1600,434,57,41,n]]} are not all equality or inequality constraints. With the exception of integer domain constraints for linear programming, domain constraints or constraints with Unequal (!=) are not supported.

General::ivar: -0.109996 is not a valid variable.

ReplaceAll::reps: {NonlinearModelFit[<<1>>]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  Is there lack of convergence?  You'll need to be more specific than it only works "manually" rather than "automatically".  Also, supplying a specific dataset that displays the problem you're having is essential.  We have no access to "gonio0159.dat".

Comment: The function `Ccal/Ccal0` is too complex to describe the data.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your quick reply. PLease I forgot  to indicate the error messages that I obatined. Here below are those messages.

Comment: NonlinearModelFit::fdssnv: Search specification 434 without variables should be a list with 1 to 4 elements.

Comment: ReplaceAll::reps: {NonlinearModelFit[<<1>>]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

Comment: General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed during this calculation.

Comment: Yes @AlexTrounev you are right by saying that the function if too complex. Me too I know that. A first solution I want to see would be to execute the 'NonlinearModelFit' to just obtain the values of the parameters b, t, L & m, Before trying to compare the fit wiht the experimental data.

Comment: @JimB, please, when I say ''manually", I mean by changing the parameters {b, t, m, L} with hands and execute the line: fig = Show[{LogPlot[Ccal/Ccal0, {n, -0.11, 0.11}, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> Red]}], with the command 'Evaluate cell'.  The spectrum that shows up can be overlayed with the experimental spectrum. A much better fitting method would be to start with the initial parametres b, t, L, m, then perform an automatic fitting and extract the values of these parameters that the 'automatic' fit has provided. This is helpful to extract the error bars,

Comment: which is an advantage of the aumomatic fit. I hope you got what I mean. Thanks again.

Comment: Please update your question with the associated error messages rather than putting those in the comments.  You also have a few grammatically incorrect statements. For example, the `NonlinearModelFit` statement gives `data` rather than `Data` (*Mathematica* is case sensitive) and you give `b`, `m`, `t`, and `L` as "values" (`{434, 41, 570, 1600}`) rather than undefined variables.

Comment: Why do you have random effects (the `(1.1*Random[])` pieces) in what is usually the deterministic part of the model?  The fitting functions that you are using assume that the model fitted is of the form `Ccal/Cca10 + error` and not the form that your code defines.  The way you currently have it, there is a different prediction for every iteration of the iterative fitting procedure.  I don't think that makes a whole lot of sense when using `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: The second coordinate of the data is many times negative.  But the ratio of `Ccal/Ccal0` (without the out-of-place random uniform numbers) seems to be always positive.  Is the second coordinate really the log of the observed ratio?

Comment: Rule #1 about nonlinear fitting: there is no such thing as "automatic nonlinear fitting". Especially with a model as complex as yours.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The only model capable to solve my problem is that one that I developed based on the theoretical concept of kinematical diffraction.

Comment: We really are trying to help but we are not as familiar with your model as you are.  Addressing the questions we've asked keeps us interested.  And when we ask silly questions,  don't hesitate to state that the questions are silly.  We can take it.  We really just want to help.

Comment: (1) In addition to the variables having been given values, there is a problem evaluating the model at zero. Removing that data point might be required. (2) It is not clear to me whether the goal is to fit `Ica[...]` or a ratio that involves some random values. If the latter, the presence of those random values is not making sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment updated with recent responses.  I'm still not sure if the data represents observations of `Log[Ccal/Ccal0]` or something else.  Below I've put in the data correction that you mentioned and made just a single function to deal with.  The data and the function with the initial parameters are not anywhere close to each other but I hope that showing what can be currently gleaned from your question, you'll supply some clarification.

```
(* Fix data issue by making all of the second coordinates positive *)
data[[All, 2]] = Abs[data[[All, 2]]];

(***********Analytical model************)
Ica[θ_?NumericQ, ϕ_?NumericQ, λ_?NumericQ, α_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ] := 
  -((2*λ^2*(-1 + Cos[L*m*n])*Cos[α]^2*(n^2*λ^2*(-2 - Cos[b*n] + 
  Cos[t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ - n*Tan[α])] + Cos[t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ + 
  n*Tan[α])] - Cos[n*(b + 2*t*Tan[α])] + Cos[b*n - t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ - 
  n*Tan[α])] + Cos[b*n + t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ + n*Tan[α])])*Sin[α]^2 + 
  2*n*Pi*λ*(Cos[t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ - n*Tan[α])] - 
  Cos[t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ + n*Tan[α])])*Sin[2*α]*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]) + 
  4*Pi^2*Cos[α]^2*(-2 + Cos[b*n] + Cos[t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ - 
  n*Tan[α])] + Cos[t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ + n*Tan[α])] + Cos[n*(b + 
  2*t*Tan[α])] - Cos[b*n - t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ - n*Tan[α])] - Cos[b*n + 
  t*((2*Pi*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))/λ + n*Tan[α])])*(Sin[θ] +       
  Sin[ϕ])^2))/(L^2*n^2*(-1 + Cos[L*n])*(n*λ*Sin[α] - 2*Pi*Cos[α]*(Sin[θ] +                  
  Sin[ϕ]))^2*(n*λ*Sin[α] + 2*Pi*Cos[α]*(Sin[θ] + Sin[ϕ]))^2)) (Exp[-280*n^2]/850);

(* Initial parameter values *)
rr = Pi/180;
θ = 0.134;
ϕ = 0.133;
λ = 1.0353234;
α = 0.1;
t0 = 570;
b0 = 434;
L0 = 800;
m0 = 41;
n0 = 0.0000364797082;
```

Now plot data and initial fit:

```
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> Red,
 AspectRatio -> 1/8, PlotLabel -> Style["Data", Bold, 18], Joined -> True]
Plot[Log[Ica[θ, ϕ, λ, α, L0, b0, t0, m0, n]] - Log[Ica[θ, ϕ, λ, α, L0, b0, t0, m0, n0]],
 {n, -0.11, 0.11}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/8, PlotLabel -> Style["Initial fit", Bold, 18]]
```

[image: Data]
[image: Initial fit]

I'm still not convinced that this is an issue of just finding better parameters.

Comment: fo the following comments:

Comment: I have tried to execute 'NonlinearModelFit' without the random components and Ccal/Ccal0 (by using just the term Ccal),  the message errors are the same: NonlinearModelFit::fdssnv: Search specification 434 without variables should be a list with 1 to 4 elements.

Comment: Or the message such as: ReplaceAll::reps: {NonlinearModelFit[{{-0.113915,-5.17371},{-0.113858,-5.06399},{-0.113801,-4.9956},{-0.113744,-4.98564},{-0.113687,-5.09572},<<41>>,{-0.111294,-4.8705},{-0.111237,-4.8653},{-0.11118,-4.9108},{-0.111123,-4.8444},<<3950>>},<<21>>,<<1>>,-<<20>>]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.    I do not  understand what these messages mean and how to fix the corresponding errors.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156701/fitting-curve-by-using-normalized-function) is a link from which I found someone who had a similar problem like me, with a complex model to fit her(his) data. As proposed in the attempt of solutions provided online, I first tried to find the good initial values of my parameters, which are those I provided in the code. After that, a first starting point may be to minimize them. I hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

Please @JimB, for your first comment:
* In your model θ and ϕ always appear as sinθ+sinϕ so you can only estimate sinθ+sinϕ and not θ and ϕ separately: θ and ϕ are two of the experimental input parameters that do not need to be fitted, they are kept fix. I do not need to fit these two parameters at all. Please keep them as they are, i.e. < 0.5°

For the second comment concerning the random component: we have added this term to our model to best fit the background representing sort of raondom atomic displacements within the lattice (Debye's term or function to take the contribution of the damages in the reduction of the scattering intensity into consideration. I have never tried fitting the data without this term. I'll try but do not expect better results. You can try to omit in the NonlinearModelFit just to check if something comes out.

Regarding the restriction 0≤α<360: α is very small and normally, it is never greater than 2°. So, as better restriction, one can limit the interval to  0≤α<2.

Concerning the last comment on the ratio Log[Lcal/Lcal0]: yes, it is always positive. The fact that the second coordinates of the data be negative is a bugg. They are all and always positive. When I plot them after uploading, the graph is correct. But when I use the mathematica's Print[] function to generate the data, it displays negative values. You can turn them into positive values or multiply the y axis of data by -1. I repeat the second coordinates are never negative. Sorry for that mistake.

Thank you for helping me, I really appreciate. I'm not good enough at programming, but I realise that I need to know it for my future carreer. Any advice or help would be very great.

Comment: While the immediate use of the questions and answers is to get you an answer, the long-term use is a repository of questions and answers that would be helpful for others.  So to that end I suggest you update your question with the necessary information and then remove your "answers" so that everything necessary is found within your original question.  That would include the updated data.  Press the "edit" text in the text string "share edit close flag protect" towards the bottom of your original question.